# Tikz Sub/superscripts within a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I just started using TikZ, and I'm still reaqcuainting myself with LaTex in general.  When defining a node in TikZ, how do I apply simple stylistic things like subscripts and superscripts?

Comment: Welcome. In the usual way. In math mode, a simple `^` is sufficient, e.g. $x^y$ and in text mode you can do `2\textsuperscript{nd}`, say, and similarly for subscripts: e.g. $a_i$. E.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[circle,draw]{$x^y$};}
\tikz{\node[circle,draw]{2\textsuperscript{nd}};}
\tikz{\node[circle,draw]{$a_i$};}
\end{document}`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.